# Wordpress - setting div above main menu but only on landing page

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to create something that I want to put above my main menu. But the issue is I only need it on landing page, on every other page that div should not be visible so I cant put that div into header.

Also I created div with Elementor and not inside the code. Div is created inside content area.

Is there any way I can show it only on landing page if I put it inside header?

Or is there any way to put it above. I tried to do it with position fixed, but that breaks once user is logged out.

Comment: Hi, Since you use Elementoir I would make a specific header (elementor model) containing your paritcular "div," whish can then be affected only to that particular lending page.